# Restrict mobile view of any website in JavaFX browser

Tags: javafx-8

I have build my own web browser using JavaFX8. I have used two webview. I want to open every website in desktop view not in mobile view in both webview and I want to add horizontal and vertical scrollbar in both webview.

I have used two webview.

Comment: I have tried to post the code but i don't know how to post code here?

Comment: please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/